# SCP (Security Content Policy) issue with pouchdb

Tags: html, security, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

I see an error in the console when running my `ionic` app on my android device:

```
Refused to connect to 'blob:http%3A//192.168.0.12%3A8100/9d72a06a-c6fa-4397-976c-41ea23f90be0' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
"default-src *". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set,
so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
i @ pouchdb.min.js:9
(index):28 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'open' on 
'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to connect to 'blob:http%3A//192.168.0.12%3A8100/9d72a06a-c6fa-4397-976c-41ea23f90be0' 
because it violates the document's Content Security Policy. 
http://192.168.0.12:8100/lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js Line: 9console.(anonymous function) @ (index):28
```

It seems to be related to te Content-Security-Policy, can you help me tune it so it works fine please ?

Thanks.
My current policy:

index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">
```

Comment: You should set that header from the server, not in the file due to security reasons

Comment: Have you already tried adding `connect-src blob:;` to your Content-Security-Policy?

Comment: @Ferrybig I don't know how to do this... poucdb connects to a cloudant DB.

Comment: @beaver no, what does it do ?

Comment: @Louis How you fixed this ?

Comment: @OmarHassan hi, I didn't, I am still unsure about how to write a good csp. If you find out let me know please !

Comment: Hi Louis, have you seen my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who's looking for a solution to this error, @beaver's comment worked for me.

I've added this:

```
connect-src * blob:;
```

I've also added a `*` to allow other connections