# How to insert form into mysql without leaving the page (javascript+html)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to insert a new user into mysql. I have tried to use jQuery, but it doesn't seem to be working. I tried to use pure javascript, but it's the same. It has no response after I click on the button. What's wrong?

```
var regBtn = document.getElementById("regBtn");
regBtn.addEventListener("click", submitForm, false);

function submitForm() {

    var acR = document.getElementById("ac2");
    var pw1 = document.getElementById("pw1");
    var shop = document.getElementById("shop");

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "http://xyz.php", true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var params = "ac=" + acR + "&pw1="+pw1 "&shop="+ shop;
    http.send(params);
    http.onload = function() {
        alert(http.responseText);
    };
}
```

Comment: Try setting the `onload` *before* calling `send`. And check the console - is there any error message?

Comment: can you be more specific about what is not working? are you getting errors in the browser javascript console, or is your PHP page itself failing?

Comment: you're missing a `+` on this line before the last pw1: `var params = "ac=" + acR + "&pw1=" pw1;` - make sure your example code is correct so we know if that itself is the problem or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a quite a few problems in your JS code, I've tidied it up here and run it locally to a page called `xyz.php`, so that'll get the AJAX call to work but you'll need to post your PHP code to get any help with your DB queries

```
    var regBtn = document.getElementById("regBtn");
    regBtn.addEventListener("click", submitForm, false);

    function submitForm() {

        var acR = document.getElementById("ac2");
        var pw1 = document.getElementById("pw1");

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // removed the http:// protocol, assuming you're going for a local AJAX call
        http.open("POST", "xyz.php", true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // get values of the form fields, don't submit the full element
        // also added the plus (+) character before the final pw1
        var params = "ac=" + acR.value + "&pw1=" + pw1.value;
        http.send(params);
        http.onload = function() {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
```

I've attached a screen shot showing [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) happily recording successful AJAX requests

[image: chrome dev tools successfully logging ajax calls]

Comment: i hv solved the problem. all because of <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"........>. if one have a problem like mine, take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807901/scp-security-content-policy-issue-with-pouchdb thx all

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a JQuery post.

```
var acR = document.getElementById("ac2");
var pw1 = document.getElementById("pw1");

$.post( "xyz.php", { ac: acR, pw1: pw1 })
.done(function( data ) {
   alert( "Data inserted: " + data );
});
```

Backend handles this post and then implement the insert action for example in NodeJs(express)

```
app.post("/xyz", function(req, res, next) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[acR] = body.ac;
    obj[pw1] = body.pw1;
    mysql.insert(obj);

});
```